# Best practices/guidance for maintaining assembly version numbers

Tags: .net, version-control, versioning, .net-assembly, assemblyversions

I'm looking for pointers, suggestions, and even dictation on how to manage the three different assembly version numbers for a .NET assembly.   The Product version is the simplest, as this seems would normally be dictated by business.  Then, the file version seems to be for versioning between deployments, where the actual assembly version is only used when shipping.

Right now I'm just looking for a simple means of labeling test and maintenance releases of an assembly on which none depend, so I am looking at auto-incrementing build and revision numbers on the file version, and for final release, copying the current file version to the assembly version.  The product is in production use, but still under development - you know - one of those small company, no change control infrastructure situations.

Comment: Check this out... http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/whats-in-a-version-number-anyway.html

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Versioning is something that I am very passionate about and have spent a long time trying to come up with an easy to use versioning system. From what you have already said in your question it is clear that you have understood one important point, the assembly version numbers are not synonymous with the product version. One is technically driven, and the other is driven by the business.

The following assumes that you use some form of source control and a build server. For context we use [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) and Subversion/Git. TeamCity is free for a small (10) number of projects and is a very good build server but there are others, some of which are completely free.

### What a version number means

What a version means to one person may mean something different to another, the general structure is major, minor, macro, micro. The way I look at a version number is to break it down into two parts. The first half describes the main version (Major) and any key updates (Minor). The second half indicates when it was built and what the source code version was. Version numbers also mean different things depending on the context, is it an API, Web App, etc.

`Major`.`Minor`.`Build`.`Revision`

- `Revision` This is the number taken from source control to identify what
  was actually built.
- `Build` This is an ever increasing number that can be used to find a
  particular build on the build server.
  It is an important number because the
  build server may have built the same
  source twice with a different set of
  parameters. Using the build number in
  conjunction with the source number
  allows you to identify what was built
  and how.
- `Minor` This should only change when there is a significant change to
  the public interface. For instance, if it is an
  API, would consuming code still be
  able to compile? This number should be reset to zero when the Major number changes.
- `Major` indicates what version of the
  product you are on. For example the
  Major of all the VisualStudio 2008
  assemblies is 9 and VisualStudio 2010
  is 10.

#### The exception to the rule

There are always exceptions to the rule and you will have to adapt as you come across them. My original approach was based on using subversion but recently I have moved to Git. Source control like subversion and source safe that use a central repository have a number that can be used to identify a particular set of sources from a given time. This is not the case for a distributed source control such as Git. Because Git uses distributed repositories that are on each development machine there is no auto incrementing number that you can use, there is a hack which uses the number of check-ins but it is ugly. Because of this I have had to evolve my approach.

`Major`.`Minor`.`Macro`.`Build`

The revision number has now gone, build has shifted to where the revision used to be and Macro has been inserted. You can use the macro how you see fit but most of the time I leave it alone. Because we use TeamCity the information lost from the revision number can be found in the build, it does mean there is a two step process but we have not lost anything and is an acceptable compromise.

### What to set

The first thing to understand is that the Assembly Version, File Version and Product Version do not have to match. I am not advocating having different sets of numbers but it makes life a lot easier when making small changes to an assembly that doesn't affect any public interfaces that you are not forced to recompile dependent assemblies. The way I deal with this is to only set the Major and Minor numbers in the Assembly Version but to set all the values in the File Version. For example:

- 1.2.0.0 (AssemblyVersion)
- 1.2.3.4 (FileVersion)

This gives you the ability to roll out hot fixes which will not break existing code because the assembly versions do not match but allow you to see the revision/build of an assembly by looking at its file version number. This is a common approach and can be seen on some open source assemblies when you look at the assembly details.

You as the Team lead would need to be responsible for incrementing the minor number when ever a breaking change is required. One solution to rolling out a required change to an interface but not breaking previous code is to mark the current one as obsolete and creating a new interface. It means that existing code is warned that the method is obsolete and could be removed at any time but doesn't require you to break everything immediately. You can then remove the obsolete method when everything has been migrated.

### How to wire it together

You could do all the above manually but it would be very time consuming, the following is how we automate the process. Each step is runnable.

- Remove the [`AssemblyVersion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [`AssemblyFileVersion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyfileversionattribute.aspx) attributes from all the project AssemblyInfo.cs files.
- Create a common assembly info file (call it VersionInfo.cs) and add it as a linked item to all your projects.
- Add `AssemblyVersion` and `AssemblyFileVersion` attributes to the version with values of "0.0.0.0".
- Create an MsBuild project that builds your solution file.
- Add in a task prior to the build that updates the VersionInfo.cs. There are a number of open source MsBuild libraries that include an AssemblyInfo task which can set the version number. Just set it to an arbitrary number and test.
- Add a property group containing a property for each of the segments of the build number. This is where you set the major and minor. The build and revision number should be passed in as arguments.

With subversion:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Version-Major>0</Version-Major>
    <Version-Minor>0</Version-Minor>
    <Version-Build Condition=" '$(build_number)' == '' ">0</Version-Build>
    <Version-Build Condition=" '$(build_number)' != '' ">$(build_number)</Version-Build>
    <Version-Revision Condition=" '$(revision_number)' == '' ">0</Version-Revision>
    <Version-Revision Condition=" '$(revision_number)' != '' ">$(revision_number)</Version-Revision>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Hopefully I have been clear but there is a lot involved. Please ask any questions. I will use any feedback to put a more concise blog post together.

- [Version numbers in a compiled assembly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carloc/archive/2008/02/22/the-meaning-of-version-numbers-in-a-compiled-assembly.aspx)
- [MSBuild Extension Pack](https://github.com/mikefourie/MSBuildExtensionPack)
- [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)

Comment: Have you considered using version tags from GitHub? I'm very curious on how that would fit into the puzzle.

Comment: @raRaRa - This is quite an old post. Whilst most of it I still stand by there are some things that I would do different. NuGet versioning has changed how I do things and I do use Git tags for successful builds but at the end of the day the version number on the assembly should tie back to the build version on the build server and the tag version in source control.

Comment: Any recommendation/blog on how to go about all this in 2024?

Comment: @jav - I have some changes that I would make to this which whilst follow the same sentiment are quite different. I would have to do it as another answer as updating the existing post would be cheeky given the number of votes.

Comment: @Bronumski I have posted this new question (maybe too specific though) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77947400/product-vs-assembly-version-number

Answer (score 60):

The [AssemblyVersion] is a very big deal in .NET.  One philosophy, encouraged by Microsoft is that you let it auto-increment, forcing *all* projects that depend on the assembly to be recompiled.  Works okayish if you use a build server.  It is never the *wrong* thing to do but beware of people carrying swords.

The other one, more closely associated with its actual meaning is that the number is representative for the versioning of the public interface of the assembly.  In other words, you only change it when you alter a public interface or class.  Since only such a change requires clients of the assembly to be recompiled.  This needs to be done manually though, the build system isn't smart enough to auto-detect such a change.

You can further extend this approach by only incrementing the version when the assembly was deployed on machines outside of your reach.  This is the approach that Microsoft uses, their .NET assemblies version numbers very rarely change.  Mostly because of the very considerable pain it causes on their customers.

So what Microsoft preaches is not what it practices.  Its build process and versioning control is however unparalleled, they even have a dedicated software engineer that monitors the process.  Didn't quite work out so well, the WaitHandle.WaitOne(int) overload in particular [caused a fair amount of pain](http://www.mikeplate.com/2008/09/26/missingmethodexception-and-waitone).  Fixed in .NET 4.0 with a very different approach, but that's getting a bit beyond the scope.

It is rather up to you and your confidence in how well you can control the build process and the release cycles to make your own choice.  Other than that, auto-incrementing the [AssemblyFileVersion] automatically is very appropriate.  With however the inconvenience that this is *not* supported.

Answer (score 11):

You could use the Build part of the version number for auto-increment.

`[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]`

In your environment a test version is a version that has a build version != 0. On release you increment the minor part and set the build part to 0, this is how you would identify released assemblies.

If you install your assemblies in the GAC your GAC gets flooded with lots of diffent versions over time, so keep that in mind. But if you use the dlls only locally, I think this is a good practice.

Comment: I like the 0 build number for release versions.

Comment: Of course this means your assembly's strong name will change with each build, whether you want it to or not.

Answer (score 11):

Adding to [Bronumskis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3905443/195651), I want to point out that after the Semantic Versioning 2.0 standard at [semver.org](http://semver.org), `Major.Minor.Build.Revision` would be illegal due to the rule that after increasing a number, all regular values to the right would have to be reset to zero.

A better way following the standard would be to use `Major.Minor+Build.Revision`. This is obivously not for use in `AssemblyVersionAttribute`, but a custom attribute or static class could be used instead.

Semver in TeamCity should be available using the Meta-runner Power Pack. For git with git-flow (especially in the .NET world), I found [GitVersion](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion) to be helpful.

Comment: Interesting, I will check this out. The version number format you mentioned could be used in the AssemblyInformationalVersion attribute.

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard and fast rule when it comes to versioning assemblies,  so feel free to try which ever would work for you,  but I would suggest you make use of 4 parts approach as you will have the flexiblity incase you want to make some changes in the future.

... 
for ex : 1.0.0.*

Reserved -  This adds additional flexiblity, incase you want to make any change in future.  But as a default,  keep it as 0.

Also,  consider signing the assembly with strong key. This will solve the assembly conflict issue incase you have multiple version of assembly registered in the GAC.  [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwb8f617.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/ng256/Assembly-Info-Generator) is an example of T4 template for auto generating assembly info. The assembly version will be incremented each time the transformation is performed.  You should only fill your project data:

```
// Names.
string projectName = "MyProjectName"; // Project (short name for COM).
string productName = "My Project Name"; // Full title.
string developerName = "Developer Name"; // Developer.
string assemblyType = "Application"; // Application, Library, etc.

// Version.
int majorVersion = 1;
int minorVersion = 0;

// Year of the start of work on the project.
string since = "2021";
```

After transforming the template you will get output such as:

```
#if COMVISIBLE
using System.EnterpriseServices;
#endif
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// General information about this assembly is provided by the following set
// attributes. Change the values of these attributes to change the information,
// related to the assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle ("My Project Name Application 1.0")] // Assembly name.
[assembly: AssemblyDescription ("My Project Name Application 1.0")] // Assembly description.
[assembly: AssemblyCompany ("Developer Name")] // Developer.
[assembly: AssemblyProduct ("Developer Name My Project Name Application")] // Product name.
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright ("© Developer Name 2021")] // Copyright.
//[assembly: AssemblyTrademark ("Developer Name ® My Project Name Application®")] // Trademark.
[assembly: AssemblyCulture ("")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion ("1.0.2110.0047")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion ("1.0.2110.0047")]
#if DEBUG
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration ("Debug")]
#else
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration ("Release")]
#endif

// Setting ComVisible to False makes the types in this assembly invisible
// for COM components. If you need to refer to the type in this assembly via COM,
// set the ComVisible attribute to TRUE for this type.
#if COMVISIBLE
[assembly: ComVisible (true)]
[assembly: ApplicationName ("MyProjectName")] // The name of the COM application.
[assembly: ApplicationID ("fc24620a-239d-4e40-b756-7ed38e82ef69")]
#else
[assembly: ComVisible (false)]
#endif
// The following GUID is used to identify the type library if this project will be visible to COM
[assembly: Guid ("e60d1ecf-6c7b-4c9b-925f-4bf07615da87")]
```