# Include version number when deploying (assembly version numbers in general)

Tags: asp.net, .net, version, assemblyinfo

How do I include the version number of a project on the pages of my web site, especially on error pages?
There is a file called AssemblyInfo.cs so I figure I could get the information from there using reflection. Do I have to manually increment the version numbers there? The file tells you that you can use default revision and build numbers by using *.

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

By this the version number will be incremented automatically it seems, but when does he do that and is it recommended to use the asterisk? Are there guidelines for manually incrementing  the number? I mean there are four digits like 1.0.0.0. What does each of these digits do?
So when I am showing the version number by using reflection I can show it at runtime. But is it possible to automatically include the number in a file so that you can figure it out without even running the project (which might not be possible in case of failure).

Comment: Hi there - your question is actually 6 different questions.  Could you narrow this down!?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768261/best-practices-guidance-for-maintaining-assembly-version-numbers) q&a from StackOverflow can probably help answer most of your questions. Hope this helps!

Comment: Basically I just want to know how to deal with version numbers in an ASP.NET application. How to include them in the project and on the web site and when to increment them.