# What is difference between NuGet and NuGet Package Manager?

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-extensions

Just a bit confused here about NuGet and NuGet Package Manager.
When I look into Visual Studio->Extension Manager-> I see NuGetPackage Manager installed - Version: 2.7.40808.167.

On the http://nuget.codeplex.com it shows the stable Version is "NuGet 2.7" and shows planned up coming version is 2.7.2

But in this document http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/nuget-faq under:  How do I check the exact version of NuGet installed? it tells to look for NuGet Package Manager version.

If anyone can shed some light on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NuGet can mean two things: the NuGet command line tool, i.e. nuget.exe, or the VisualStudio extension called NuGet Package Manager. They are related but independent, so it's possible to have different versions of nuget.exe and NuGet Package Manager installed on the same machine.

See [Best practices/guidance for maintaining assembly version numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768261/best-practices-guidance-for-maintaining-assembly-version-numbers) to help you understand the version number you see. "2.7.40808.167" means version 2.7, build 40808, revision 167.

2.7.2 is an internal version number for tracking development, not the version number in the released files.